# Onclick event using fireevent() function is not working in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

```
<div id="member_sel_div" style="">
    <table class="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" summary="">
        <tbody>
               <tr class="heding">
                   <tr class="odd">
                           <td valign="top" width="4%">

                               <input id="mgrp_-1" class="reset" type="checkbox" onclick="showMembers(-1, 0)" value="-1" name="member_group_id[]" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"/>

                               <span class="jquery-checkbox jquery-checkbox-checked" style="-moz-user-select: none;">


                              <span class="mark jquery-checkbox-hover">

                              <img width="24" height="24" src="/purebenefits/dev/images/empty.png"/>

                             </span>
                         </span>
                    </td>

                   <td valign="top" style="padding-left:0;">NO GROUP</td>

            </tr>
```

I am working on a test case where  more than  one checkbox will appear and onclicking each check box  it will call a function showMembers(checkbox value, 0)

In my test case i have first counted the number of checkboxes and then using loop i am able to click each checkboxes as well , but on clicking the checkbox its onclick function is not firing that why  i am not able to proceed.  i have used fireevent function also but the result is same

i am using selenium IDE  , html code of the section is given above and the code i have written for selenium ide is  given below

```
<tr>
    <td>assertTextPresent</td>
    <td>New Quote</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>name=insurance_type_id</td>
    <td>label=Group Life Assurance</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
    <td>Policy Features </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertTextPresent</td>
    <td>Bronze</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[@id='product_list_div']/table[@class='priceTable']/tbody/tr/th[4]/label/input[@id='prodid_6']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeXpathCount</td>
    <td>//div[@id='member_sel_div']/table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr[@class='odd']/td/input[@type='checkbox']/</td>
    <td>count</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${count}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>alert(&quot;Number of Group : ${count}&quot;)</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>j</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>i</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars.count;}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>storedVars.i&lt;=${count}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${i}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${j}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>${i}-${j}</td>
    <td>k</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>window.document.getElementsByName('member_group_id[]')[${k}].value</td>
    <td>abc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${abc}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[@id='member_sel_div']/table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr[@class='odd']/td/input[@value='${abc}']/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>fireEvent</td>
    <td>//div[@id='member_sel_div']/table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr[@class='odd']/td/input[@value='${abc}']</td>
    <td>&quot;click&quot;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars.i++;}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: try `clickAt` instead if `click` and `fireEvent`

Comment: @Aleh Douhi 

As per your suggestion i tried clickAt instead if click and fireEvent  , but the onclick event is not firing .

Comment: there was  radio button  in that page where onclick event is firing properly  but  when it comes to checkbox  onclick event is not firing

Comment: Btw, is this a correct syntax for `fireEvent`? First of all, delete quotes near `click`. Then, I'm not sure that `click` is a supported event for `fireEvent` command. Try `fireEvent | locator | focus` then `click | locator`

Comment: @Aleh Douhi  in site check boxes will generate dynamically so number of checbox can vary ,when i am using  clink event  with the locator [ //div[@id='member_sel_div']/table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr[@class='odd']/td/span/span/img   ]  checkbox is getting clicked and the corresponding pannel is opening  but when i am using click ,fireevent and focus with the locator [ //div[@id='member_sel_div']/table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr[@class='odd']/td/input[@value=${abc}]/   ]  chechbox are getting clicked but corresponding panel is not opening.

Comment: but if i use [ //div[@id='member_sel_div']/table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr[@class='odd']/td/span/span/img ] this as xpath location then only forst check box is getting clicked all time , and also in this way i am not able to distinguish between the checkboxes as there is no way i can send the input id or value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Focusing on that element before applying fireEvent ? That might be a case.

Comment: i used the focusing event but result is same.
<tr>
 <td>focus</td>
 <td>//div[@id='member_sel_div']/table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr[@class='odd']/td/input[@value='${abc}']/</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr> <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[@id='member_sel_div']/table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr[@class='odd']/td/input[@value='${abc}']/</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>fireEvent</td>
 <td>//div[@id='member_sel_div']/table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr[@class='odd']/td/input[@value='${abc}']</td>
 <td>&quot;click&quot;</td>
</tr>
can u please suggest if any mistake is there

Comment: It's hard to debug just by looking html.I suggest you to move on selenium RC or webdriver.There you can get more capability in programming and debugging your test case as well.
There are also the methods in which you can write your own java script to execute.